# export -f in .bashrc after upgrade to bash 4.3.30 kills builtins?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, function

I recently upgraded my bash (Mac OS X 10.6.8) from 3.2.48(1) to 4.3.30(1) via macports, and while the install seems to have gone smoothly, the two spots in my ~/.bashrc where I had `export -f myfunc;` seem to produce some unexpected results.  Various things, including `man` and `more`, give the following error:

`/bin/sh: line 6: 'BASH_FUNC_myfunc%%': not a valid identifier`

There were two functions defined in ~/.bashrc that used `export -f` to allow another script to call that function; the error will refer to the first one present in ~/.bashrc, I have no idea where the line number comes from.  The secondary scripts work normally, and removing `export` or the `-f` flag removes the error but clearly results in an inability for the scripts to call the function.

What is causing this behavior and how can I export my functions properly in bash 4?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)

Comment: Replacing the system `bash` (which I assume you did, given that `/bin/sh` is involved) with 4.3 is probably a bad idea. Either use Apple's Bash Update, or at least grab 3.2.57 (latest patch in that series) from `macports` or elsewhere.

Comment: @Travis I'm aware of Shellshock, but it doesn't make `export -f` pointless.